# Debian 9 installation on HP laptop fails

Tags: debian-installer

Last week I downloaded from debian repo the debian 9.8 installation image and over the last couple of days I'm trying to install it on a HP laptop.

The laptop has uefi hardware so i did the following partitions:
[image]

So far so good..

Then i selected the repository from where i will pull update packages and process stuck at this screen, no matter how much time i wait:
[image]

What shall i do in order to find where the problem is?

Comment: There do appear to be sporadic reports of this:  https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=794410#150  There are a couple of mentions that BIOS updates helped. But not for everyone.